# Return all possible Cuts of array A If you have defined number of parts M

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am trying to prepare for job interview using codility and i came up with a question which is not codility task for which i don't know to write algorithm that gives solution. I know it sounds like college homework but sadly those days are gone for me and we never had this complex algorithms there so i have no colleague to ask for solution and that is why I am asking you guys here.

I am most comfortable in javascript but any language will do.

Task:

> Lets say you have input Array A with with input length N and you have
>   also input number M which defines how many array cuts you need to
>   have. The goal is to return all possible cuts.
>
> N/M <= 1

So for example if you have Array A = [1,2,3,4] and M = 2

solution is array L containing arrays

[ [1] [2,3,4] ]

[ [1,2] [3,4] ]

[ [1,2,3] [4] ]

Comment: You don't allow *empty* parts, do you? E.g. `[[][1, 2, 3, 4]]` is *incorrect* partition?

Comment: I don't allow empty parts. Do you maybe have a more efficient solution than the one posted?

Comment: Share your thoughts with us. Do not simply expect us to solve your problem. Where did you got stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure that more efficient algorithms for this exist, but I would do something like this.

```
def findAllCuts(array,length,cuts):
    cuts = []
    for i in range(0,length-cuts):
        cut = array[:i]
        subCuts = findAllCuts(array[i:],length-i,cuts-1)
        for j in range(len(subCuts)):
            cuts.add(cut+subCuts[j])
    return cuts
```

It should go through all the possible first cuts, and recurse over all future cuts given that first cut.
If empty cuts aren't allowed, change the 0 in the 3rd line to a 1, so that the cut must contain at least one element.

Comment: Handy tip: To format a code block, either indent the entire block 4 spaces, or select the code and hit `ctrl-k` or the `{}` icon at the top of the edit box, which will insert the 4 spaces automatically. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.